# I can't find my file (on windows) xls after exported - SqliteToExcel Android Studio

Tags: android, excel, csv, android-sqlite, export-to-excel

I'm having a problem with my project.
I'm making an app that must export in CSV and XLS, I have searched for tutorials all over the internet but some I have not understood, I got this library SqliteToExcel, quite useful, it is working ... What happens is that after exporting the file does not appear in windows until I reboot the device, I tried everything, clean the project and rebuild it many times and nothing serves me ... The same thing happened with the CSV but with some lines of code it was resolved but with Excel they don't work.

ExportExcel:

```
    public void exportExcel () {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MultiEntry/Excel");
    final String doc = file.toString() + "/" + TABLE_NAME + "-" + currentDateandTime + ".xls";
    String filename = TABLE_NAME+"-"+currentDateandTime+".xls";
    Log.d(TAG, doc);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        SQLiteToExcel sqliteToExcel = new SQLiteToExcel(context, "MultiEntry.db", file.getPath());

        sqliteToExcel.exportSingleTable(TABLE_NAME, filename, new SQLiteToExcel.ExportListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(String file) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "File Excel created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e)
        {System.out.println("Error"+e);}
```

This is the ExportCSV:

```
    public void exportCSV () {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MultiEntry/CSV");
    final String doc = file.toString() + "/" + TABLE_NAME + "-" + currentDateandTime + ".csv";
    Log.d(TAG, doc);

    if(!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(doc, true);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Records", null );

        fileWriter.append(COLUMN_ID);
        fileWriter.append(",");
        fileWriter.append(COLUMN_ONE);
        fileWriter.append(",");
        fileWriter.append(COLUMN_TWO);
        fileWriter.append(",");
        fileWriter.append(COLUMN_THREE);
        fileWriter.append(",");
        fileWriter.append(COLUMN_FOUR);
        fileWriter.append("\n");

        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0 ){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                fileWriter.append(cursor.getString(0));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(cursor.getString(1));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(cursor.getString(2));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(cursor.getString(3));
                fileWriter.append(",");
                fileWriter.append(cursor.getString(4));
                fileWriter.append("\n");
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There's not records on database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        db.close();
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();

        String[] paths = new String[1];
        paths[0] = doc;
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, paths, null, null);

        Toast.makeText(context, "File CSV created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error"+e);
    }

}
```

The block of CSV works pretty well, i have not problems, the files appears when i connect the device to the computer, but with the ExcelExport is another history, someone knows a solution?

Comment: `but with some lines of code it was resolved ` Well how did you resolve it?

Comment: String[] paths = new String[1];
        paths[0] = doc;
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, paths, null, null);

With these three lines i fixed the problem of CSV export, but with XLS export don't work. Some ideas?

Comment: try worksheet https://elirehema.github.io/worksheet/

Comment: The problem is not that, i can create the file because with and app i can see it, but if i don't restart the phone i can not see the files on the computer... That's the problem...